# Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 17.3.99]

Tags: firebase, flutter, onesignal

I want to send device-to-device notifications in flutter using OneSignal.
I have tried all the things google service update Gradle version update, flutter clean, restart, rebuild

In flutter adding dependency of Onesignal following error occurs

## Error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 17.3.99].
     Required by:
         project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 16.1.99].
     Required by:
         project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

project build gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build gradle

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         // ...
         maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
     }
     dependencies {
         // ...
         // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
         classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'

     }
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.ml_kit_in_flutter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}


googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Here is all the dependency of pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_tts: ^0.6.0
  camera: ^0.5.8+11
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  speech_to_text: ^2.4.1
  clipboard: ^0.1.2+8
  table_calendar: ^2.2.3
  tflite: ^1.1.1
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  tflite_flutter: ^0.5.0
  image: ^2.1.12
  provider: ^3.1.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.3
  http: ^0.12.2
  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0+1"
  firebase_storage: "^7.0.0"

  dio: ^3.0.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+15
  geolocator: ^5.3.2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  path: ^1.7.0
  uuid: ^2.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.8
  awesome_notifications: ^0.0.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do upgrade to Gradle 6.0 this will fix the build issue . To upgrade Gradle update the version number
in your project's gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file.

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

as mentioned here https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/94#issuecomment-626399384

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions and went back to One Signal documentation to get rid of this issue.

Add the following lines to your `android/app/build.gradle`

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
         // ...
         maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
      }
      dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
       classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
      }
    }

   apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```